# Datagrip: Unexpected update count received

Tags: mysql, mariadb, datagrip

I have a table with 2 columns: `sample_id` and `sample_period`.

`sample_id`: it is an ID of samples stored in another table.

`sample_period`: it is an ID of chronologies which I stored in another table.

I could not make sample_id unique or primary as they can be duplicated (a sample can have more chronologies).

Example:

| sample_id | sample_period |
| --- | --- |
| 377 | 2 |
| 377 | 3 |

I am using DataGrip to deal with my tables (MariaDB), but I cannot delete or update some rows. It is a large database for my PhD project, so recreating the table would be almost impossible at this point. Do you have any advice?

Whenever I try to delete or update a row I get the error: *Unexpected update count received (Actual: 3, Expected: 1)*

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Log
[image: Log]

Comment: What were the statements used to delete/update a row ?

Comment: I assume Roberto means deleteing or updating from DataGrip's UI

Comment: I was using the DataGrip GUI to update the table. So I was just trying to delete the row using the application

Comment: Can you please show the query which is run? It can be seen in the Services window: https://imgur.com/p56QmbK

Comment: I just added the query editing my question above. The problem is that a primary key field is missing, so whenever I try to delete sample_id = 377, there are more rows with the same value. I tried already adding a new auto-increment primary key field, but the thing is that I can't seem to auto-fill this field using the datagrip GUI (otherwise I would have to fill 500 rows)

Comment: Finally was able to solve it using ALTER TABLE faunal_chronologies ADD chrono_unique_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

Answer (score 0):

Close DataGrip and reopen then select all repeating rows at once and press '-' or delete rows. It will hopefully work.